# Solutions to two Bézout equations solve a third one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ and $q$ be relatively prime integers, and let $a, b, c, d$ be the minimal solutions of

$$\begin{align}
ap - bq & = 1 \\
cq - dp & = 1. 
\end{align}
$$

Then I want to show that $$ac - bd = 1.$$

The obvious strategy of mashing on the algebra might work, but I haven't been able to make it work. For example, multiplying the first equation by $d$, the second by $a$, and adding, yields $(ac-bd)q = a+d$, which looks promising, and if I could show that $a+d=q$, I would be done. But…

Comment: (This is not a homework assignment.)

Comment: Seems related to continued fractions. If $p/q = [a_0,\dots,a_n]$ with $a_n>2$ then $a/b$ and $c/d$ are $[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}]$ and $[a_0,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n-1]$, I believe (not respectively.] Then $a/b$ and $c/d$ are also consecutive fractions in a continued fraction, so $ad-bc=\pm 1$ with the sign obviously determined by some other step. But I can't prove all these relationships :) And you have to prove the case $q=1$ separately, probably.

Comment: Yes, definitely. But dragging in continued fractions seems to me a step farther along the road that I didn't want to go down in my Farey sequence answer below. ☺

Comment: Well, continued fractions are just a form of the Euclidean algorithm, which is also directly related to Bézout pairs. (Wish you had put that name in the body so I could easy copy the special 'z' :) )

Comment: It's below, but here you go: Bézout

Comment: Seems like there should be an eigenish way of doing this, then again, as a physicist, that's my hammer

Comment: Yeah, or something involving $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\p&q\end{vmatrix} = -\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\p&q\end{vmatrix} = -1$ or something like that.

Comment: Do you mean minimal **positive** solutions? (And assume $p,q>0$?)

Comment: I was only thinking of $p,q>0$, but I'd be interested in a discussion of why it makes a difference. I don't know if I mean minimal positive solutions.

Comment: If you don't know whether you mean "positive", please reflect on the fact that without this restriction there are no minimal solutions.

Comment: If that is so, then clearly I did mean "positive".

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume $p, q > 1$ (I'll leave the other cases to you).

The solutions of $x p - y q = 1$ are of the form $x = a + m q$, $y = b + m p$ for integers $m$, where $(a, b)$ is one solution.  If we choose $a$ with
$0 \le a < q$, then $b = (a p - 1)/q$ with $-1/q \le b < p - 1/q$, and thus
$0 \le b < p$.  Moreover, it's easy to see they can't be $0$.
This is the "minimal solution": $a$ is the integer with 
$0 < a < q$ and $a \equiv p^{-1} \mod q$, and $b$ is the integer with
$0 < b < p$ and $b \equiv -q^{-1} \mod p$.  Similarly, $c$ is the integer with
$0 < c < p$ and $c \equiv q^{-1} \mod p$, and $d$ is the integer with
$0 < d < q$ and $d \equiv -p^{-1} \mod q$.
  Now $a + d \equiv 0 \mod q$, and since $0 < a+d < 2q$ the only possibility is $a+d=q$.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way to prove it but it seems roundabout, involving properties of Farey sequences:

The first two Bézout relations show that that $\frac ba,\frac pq, \frac cd$ are consecutive terms in a Farey sequence, I think.  But then we know that $\frac ba, \frac cd$ are consecutive in the previous Farey sequence which omits $\frac pq$, and the third relation, $ac- bd = 1$,  follows from this.

Or if you prefer, once we have the Farey sequence, $a+d = q$  (and $b+c = p$) because $\frac pq$ is the mediant of $\frac ba$ and $\frac cd$, and, as I observed in the question, once we have $a+d=q$, we win.

But I feel that there should be some more direct proof,  not involving Farey sequences explicitly, or coming from the same place that the Farey sequence properties came from in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:(x,y) = (a,b)\:$ solves $\rm\:p\, x\! -\! q\, y\, =\, 1\:$ and is minimal $\rm\ 0 \le a < q,\:$ then the minimal solution with opposite signs is  "neighbor"
$\rm\ (d,c)\, =\, -((a,b)-(q,p))\, =\, (q\!-\!a,p\!-\!b).\:$ Thus

$$\rm ac-bd\ =\ \left|\begin{array}{cc}\rm a &\rm b\\ \rm d & \rm c\end{array}\right|\ =\ \left|\begin{array}{cc}\rm a &\rm b\\ \rm q\!-\!a \!&\! \rm p\!-\!b\end{array}\right|\ =\ \left|\begin{array}{cc}\rm a &\rm b\\ \rm q & \rm p\end{array}\right|\ =\ ap-bq = 1\quad\ {\bf QED}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider your first equation in $\mathbb{Z}_q$, you get that $a = p^{-1}$, and that is unique (modulo $q$). From the second one it is $-d = p^{-1}$, so $a \equiv -d \pmod q$, and similarly $b \equiv -c \pmod p$. Writing $d = -a + r q$ and $c = -b + s p$, and substituting into the second equation:
$$
\begin{align*}
(b + s p) q - (a + r q) p &= 1 \\
-b q + a p                &= 1 - s p q + r p q \\
1                         &= 1 + p q (r - s)  \\
0                         &= p q (r - s) \\
r                         &= s
\end{align*}
$$
So $d = - a + r q$, $c = - b + r p$.
Thus, $a c - b d = a (- b + r p) - b (- a + r q) = (a p - b q) r = r$.

Comment: You missed some signs...

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Now you're jumping to conclusions with $d=-a$ and $c=-b$: should be $d=q-a$ and $c=p-b$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I believe now I fixed all...

Answer (score 0):

In general (even in other Euclidean rings) the Bézout coefficients of $p,q$ are unique only modulo $\def\lcm{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm(p,q)/p=q/\gcd(p,q)$ respectively modulo $\lcm(p,q)/q=p/\gcd(p,q)$, since
$$
  sa+tb=s'p+t'q\iff (s-s')p+(t-t')q=0
$$
and minimal nonzero solutions (in terms of divisibility) $x,y$ to $xa+yb=0$ are $x=\lcm(p,q)/p,y=-\lcm(p,q)/q$. In case $\gcd(p,q)=1$ this simplifies to $x=q,y=-p$.

Assume $p,q>0$.
Now if $$s=a,\quad t=-b$$ give a solution of $sp+tq=1$ with $s$ minimal subject to $s>0$, then $$s=a-q,\quad t=-b+p$$ give another solution, with $s$ maximal subject to $s\leq0$.

Note that $ap-bq=1$ implies $b\geq0$, and $(a-q)p+(p-b)q=1$ with $a-q\leq0$ implies $p-b>0$, so $t=-b$ is also maximal subject to $t\leq0$ and $t=p-b$ is minimal subject to $t>0$.

This means we've also got our other minimal pair, namely $c=p-b$ and $d=q-a$. But then $ac-bd=a(p-b)-b(q-a)=ap-bq=1$.